# styled-components - what are the accepted types for the "as" polymorphic prop?

Tags: styled-components

The documentation does not seem to state what types can be passed to the "as" polymorphic prop. I know that a string can be passed in, but can it accept anything else?

Answer (score -1):

The `as` prop is used when determining what element name to pass to the eventual `createElement(element, props)` call to the react API, so any value you pass in will be used as the elements tag.

i.e.

```
<Button>Button</Button>                   =>   <Button>Button</Button>
<Button as="a" href="/">Link</Button>     =>   <a href="/">Link</a>
<Button as="div">Div</Button>             =>   <div>Div</div>
<Button as="MyButton">My Button<Button>   =>   <MyButton>My Button</MyButton>
```